# smbus Import Error

Tags: python, i2c, pip

I'm trying to use the module 'smbus' on python3. I've downloaded it - when I try to download smbus, it says that smbus is up to date and installed. However, when I try to use it, it says the module is not found. I've found a similar problem with pip3. It's downloaded but pip is an unrecognized command.
Thank you!

EDIT 1: I think this is because of a mix up of Python 2/3

EDIT 2: when I run `apt-cache search smbus`, I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ apt-cache search smbus
python-smbus - Python bindings for Linux SMBus access through i2c-dev
pypy-smbus-cffi - This Python module allows SMBus access through the I2C /dev
python3-smbus - Python 3 bindings for Linux SMBus access through i2c-dev
```

EDIT 3:
I downloaded smbus by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python3-smbus
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the output of command `apt-cache search smbus`? Could you also edit your question to show how you downloaded smbus and where from?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are only downloading modules and not installing them. Here's how to do it.

1. **Installing pip:** `sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip`
2. **Installing smbus:** `sudo apt-get install python-smbus python3-smbus python-dev python3-dev`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I run those commands, the terminal says that both pip and smbus are up to date.

Comment: @IssacJacob Did you fix that? Having the same issue...

Comment: try installing smbus2: pip install smbus2